# Optimize MySQL Query - single table with SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a single table with ~ 1.5 mio entries and this query:

```sql
SELECT id 
FROM abc.items as I 
where revisit < '2022-11-17T00:00:00Z' 
AND type = 10 
AND firstdelivery = (
                        select min(firstdelivery) 
                        from abc.items 
                        WHERE I.polizzennummer = polizzennummer
                    ) 
LIMIT 50
```

Which takes about 120-180 seconds to run.
The revisit is the part which changes the most, this is a query which runs every day.

Table schema:

```sql
'id','int(10) unsigned','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'polizzennummer','varchar(64)','YES','MUL',NULL,''
'type','tinyint(4)','YES','MUL',NULL,''
'revisit','datetime','YES','MUL',NULL,''
'status','tinyint(4)','YES','',NULL,''
'ts','datetime','YES','',NULL,''
'grund','text','YES','',NULL,''
'firstdelivery','datetime','YES','MUL',NULL,''
```

Explain Output:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'I', NULL, 'ref', 'idx_abc_type,idx_abc_revisit,idx_abc_type_revisit_firstdelivery', 'idx_abc_type', '2', 'const', '499036', '50.00', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'abc', NULL, 'ref', 'polizzennummer,idx_abc_polizzennummer_firstdelivery', 'idx_abc_polizzennummer_firstdelivery', '195', 'abc.I.polizzennummer', '7', '100.00', 'Using index'
```

The table index output:

```
'abc', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '998072', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '0', 'id_UNIQUE', '1', 'id', 'A', '998072', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'polizzennummer', '1', 'polizzennummer', 'A', '117288', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_type', '1', 'type', 'A', '10', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_revisit', '1', 'revisit', 'A', '93553', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_firstdelivery', '1', 'firstdelivery', 'A', '998072', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_polizzennummer_firstdelivery', '1', 'polizzennummer', 'A', '125237', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_polizzennummer_firstdelivery', '2', 'firstdelivery', 'A', '998072', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_type_revisit_firstdelivery', '1', 'type', 'A', '10', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_type_revisit_firstdelivery', '2', 'revisit', 'A', '116078', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'abc', '1', 'idx_abc_type_revisit_firstdelivery', '3', 'firstdelivery', 'A', '998072', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Im not sure how i could optimize this query further.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: If you can read it, then maybe you can fix it

Comment: To show us a schema please Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` in phpMyAdmin or similiar or the mysql command line and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Please then hover your cursor over the `query-optimization` lozenge and read the tool-tip to see what is required for a question of this type

Comment: That date smells like "midnight this morning".  You could replace it with `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure out your indices from what you included in the question.  Here are the indices I would suggest for this query.  For the correlated subquery, use:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1.items (polizzennummer, firstdelivery);
```

This index should allow for rapid evaluation given each row in the outer query.  For the outer query itself, you may try:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON abc.items (type, revisit, firstdelivery);
```

This covers the `WHERE` clause of the outer query.

Note that your current query is using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, which does not make much sense.  You should add an `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query.

Comment: `type` (equality test) needs to be before `revisit` (range test).

Answer (score 0):

You want the first delivery and only show it if its type is 10 and its revisit date is before 2022-11-17. But in order to do this you select all candidates, and for each you select all rows with the same polizzennummer. This can mean that you run the same subquery again and again.

Three approaches to help here:

Idea #1: Get the minimum firstdelivery once per polizzennummer

```
SELECT id 
FROM abc.items
WHERE revisit < '2022-11-17T00:00:00Z' 
AND type = 10
AND (polizzennummer, firstdelivery) IN
(
  SELECT polizzennummer, MIN(firstdelivery)
  FROM abc.items
  GROUP BY polizzennummer
);
```

Idea #2: Stop looking when you find an earlier firstdelivery

```
SELECT i.id 
FROM abc.items i 
WHERE i.revisit < '2022-11-17T00:00:00Z' 
AND i.type = 10
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT null
  FROM abc.items i2
  WHERE i2.polizzennummer = i.polizzennummer
  AND i2.firstdelivery < i.firstdelivery
);
```

Idea #3: Find the minimum firstdelivery for each row and continue working on that dataset

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT i.*, MIN(firstdelivery) OVER (PARTITION BY polizzennummer) AS min_firstdelivery
  FROM abc.items i 
) with_min_fd
WHERE firstdelivery = min_firstdelivery
AND revisit < '2022-11-17T00:00:00Z' 
AND type = 10;
```

As to indexes: Your index idx_abc_polizzennummer_firstdelivery on abc.items(polizzennummer, firstdelivery) should suffice for above queries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried all three but the results are not better
The first query took 229 seconds
The second query took 217 seconds
The third query is not possible as the server version is still 5.7 :(

What all have in common is that I see about 20mbyte/s InnoDB Disk reads and about 40-60k read reqs. I assume this comes from scanning the complete table?

I can't figure out why this is so damn slow. Your suggestions make sense but they are still slow. 
Do you have some other inputs which could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: No, sorry. This is a very old MySQL version. I suppose that the current optimizer is better than the old one, but that's just guessing and doesn't help you when you must work with that ancient software. I don't really know MySQL. Maybe your table statistics are stale and you need to refresh them. or maybe it just takes this time. If you run it once a day and it runs for three minutes, who cares?

Comment: Well, the query runs few hundred times a day, just the date changes every day. Sorry if i was not clear about this.

Most of the times its ok but it runs through some services where we then run into app and/or system timeouts which is pretty bad. 
We could increase those timeouts but that's would be just the last resort as it would get worse every day as the data increases.

Maybe we could try to update to a 8.x version. I will suggest it and lets see that happens

Comment: If this is really time critical, then you might want to consider a separate lookup clone table holding the minimum firstdelivery row per polizzennummer. You'd keep it up-to-date with triggers, and thus you'd have the information you need right away.

Comment: Good luck with the upgrade idea!

Comment: My luck with `OVER` has been underwhelming when it comes to performance.  (I can't predict the performance for this particular usage.)

Answer (score 0):

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is somewhat meaningless -- which 50 rows do you want?

A "dependent subquery" in a `WHERE` clause is quite costly, so...

Try this reformulation:

```
SELECT  I.id
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  polizzennummer, min(firstdelivery)
            from  abc.items
            WHERE type = 10    -- ??
            GROUP BY  polizzennummer 
    ) AS mins
    JOIN  abc.items as I  ON I.firstdelivery = mins.polizzennummer
    where  I.revisit <  '2022-11-17T00:00:00Z'
      AND  I.type = 10
    ORDER BY  ???
    LIMIT  50
```

after adding these composite indexes:

```
INDEX(type, firstdelivery, revisit,  id)
INDEX(polizzennummer, firstdelivery)
INDEX(polizzennummer, type, firstdelivery)
```

I am unclear whether the derived table needs to limit the tests to type=10.  If it is needed, the third index is needed.